# How to call a function inside javascript when clicking a link button inside a table generated by callback event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
       function ReceiveServerData(retValue) {          
        var val = retValue.split('#')
        var ch1= val[1].split(',');
        if (val[0] == 1) {
            var tab = "";
           //codes
            var row = ch1.split("¥");
                for (n = 0; n <= row.length - 1; n++) {
                    var col = row[n].split("µ");
                    tab += "<td style='width:5%;text-align:left'><a href onclick ='Documents(" + col[0] + "," + i + ")'  style='text-align:left;'>Download Attachment </td>";
             //codes

        }
    }         
    function Documents(ID,i) {
        //codes
    }
```

it doesn't seem to work correctly though. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do here. First of all you split a string 4 times! And what is "inside" javascript mean?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work correctly" what's the problem you are encountering?

Comment: remove `href` attribute from `<a>` tag !

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
tab += "<td style='width:5%;text-align:left'><a href onclick ='Documents(" + col[0] + "," + i + ")'  style='text-align:left;'>Download Attachment </td>";
```

to this:

```
tab += "<td style='width:5%;text-align:left'><a href='#' onclick='Documents(" + col[0] + "," + i + ")'  style='text-align:left;'>Download Attachment </td>";
```

tips:
1. You should give a "#" to href else it will go refresh your page.

2. You should connect the string between "onclick" and "=" to make html template reasonable.